# I am facing problem to install Orca in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

(D:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Dell\Documents>conda install -c plotly plotly-orca==1.2.1 psutil requests
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment D:\Anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
conda-package-handling: 1.6.1-py36h62dcd97_0
plotly-orca:            1.2.1-1               plotly
tqdm:                   4.46.0-py_0
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:                  4.3.27-py36hcbae3bd_0        --> 4.8.3-py36_0
conda-env:              2.6.0-h36134e3_1             --> 2.6.0-1
menuinst:               1.4.8-py36h870ab7d_0         --> 1.4.16-py36he774522_0
psutil:                 5.2.2-py36he84b5ac_0         --> 5.7.0-py36he774522_0
pycosat:                0.6.2-py36hf17546d_1         --> 0.6.3-py36he774522_0
requests:               2.18.4-py36h4371aae_1        --> 2.23.0-py36_0
vc:                     14-h2379b0c_1                --> 14.1-h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime:         14.0.25123-hd4c4e62_1        --> 14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_2
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.46.0-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Attempting to roll back.

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

(D:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Dell\Documents>

Comment: Have you tried creating a new environment with the required packages?

Comment: Does the problem persist after `conda clean --all --yes`?

Comment: Yes same problem.